# GRUB's menu.lst deleted after a kernel update

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I have installed ubuntu through wubi and all was well until I updated to the next kernel version.
I am now trying to boot into ubuntu and it shows me the GRUB rescue command line.
I am able to boost windows and the problem seems to be related to the fact that I have no menu.lst on ubuntu\disks\boot\grub and also it might be related to the fact that [wubi wasn't installed to the drive where windows is installed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/610898) but I am not sure.
How do I recover menu.lst? Does the problem lay somewhere else?
Is there a way to read the data with a windows tool to just recover my data?

Comment: Can you try to boot into a Live CD and reinstall GRUB

Comment: @MarkRooney: Yes I can. Will it boot the wubi installation?

Comment: It should but thinking about it some more I would first run Boot Info Script from the live CD and post the output here - details on how to do this are here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1291280. I suspect the kernel update may have created an error in the MBR of your Windows partition

Comment: @MarkRooney: But my windows boots just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into Ubuntu with a live CD or USB then install boot-repair ---follow the instructions.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

[image]