# Ubuntu update deleted entries from grub

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, updates

My computer currently has Fedora, Ubuntu, and Windows installed.

I just updated Ubuntu 12.04, and on restarting, the Fedora entry was gone from GRUB. Ubuntu and Windows remained, though.

I have looked at these threads:

- [Fedora login gone after Ubuntu updates on a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180752/fedora-login-gone-after-ubuntu-updates-on-a-dual-boot)
- http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=279221
- [GRUB's menu.lst deleted after a kernel update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29145/grubs-menu-lst-deleted-after-a-kernel-update)

However, I cannot figure out how to mount the drive as suggested. It does not appear in the list on the left side of nautilus as shown in the links above.

[image: no fedora :(]

I also tried running the following as suggested above:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

But this gave scary errors:

> /usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Attempting to install GRUB to a
>   partitionless disk or to a partition.  This is a BAD idea..
>   /usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only
>   be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists
>   are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged.. /usr/sbin/grub-setup:
>   error: will not proceed with blocklists.

The highlighted drive below is where Fedora lives.

[image]

Thanks for any help reversing Ubuntu's decision to delete this from GRUB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lvm2 support is not provided by default, you have to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2
```

You should then update grub.  Since it will now be able to read the lvm2 partition, it should find Fedora and insert it into the grub menu:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I've added 'sudo' to the update grub command.  I think it's required - but I guess you worked that out.